# How to generate exact numbers in a line

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am doing an algorithm of number in the cards, so the purpose is this:

```
.|15|23|.|44|.|63|.|86
.|17|25|.|47|.|66|.|88
.|19|28|.|49|.|69|.|89
```

The dot (.) is an empty cell, in each row there must be 4 dots (empty cells) and 5 numbers, but vertically in each column it goes like this:

first column - from 1 to 9, second column from 10 to 20, third column from 30 to 40, fourth column from 40 to 50 and go on, so what I've tried:

```
for(var y:int = 0; y < TICKET_MAX_NUM; y++)
{
    var l:Label = new Label();
    l.name = 'num_' + y;
    l.width = 25;
    l.height = 21;
    var rand:*;
    if(y == 0)
    {
        rand = UtilFunctions.randomRange(9 * multiplier, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            rand = UtilFunctions.randomRange(multiplier * 10, multiplier * 10 - 10);
        }
        while(existNumber(rand, randomNumbers));
    }

    randomNumbers.push(rand);
    l.styleName = 'ticket_number';
    l.text = rand.toString();
    t.addChild(l);
    if(multiplier == 9)
    {
        multiplier = 1;
        while(emptyLeft > 0)
        {
            rand = UtilFunctions.randomRange(y, min );
            //randomNumbers.splice(rand, 1);
            var num = t.getChildByName('num_' + rand);
            num.text = '{' + rand.toString() + '}';
            emptyLeft--;
        }
        min += 9;
        emptyLeft = 4;
    }
    else
    {
        multiplier++;
    }
}
```

But I can't generate exactly 4 empty cells and 5 numbers.  Something is wrong, but I can't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're producing a matrix of unique random numbers.

Variables:

```
var data:Array = []; // multidimensional matrix array collection
var x:uint; // columns
var y:uint; // rows
var n:uint; // number
```

Code to generate set, then randomly select each number only once:

```
for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    data.push([]);

    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
    {
        data[x].push((10 * x) + n);
    }
}

for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
{
    var row:String = "";

    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        n = getRandomNumber(data[x]);
        row += n.toString() + "|";
    }

    trace(row);
}
```

Utility function to randomly select a number from an array, removing that number after use:

```
public function getRandomNumber(set:Array):uint
{
    return (set.splice(int(Math.random() *
                           set.length), 1)[0]);
}
```

Here are examples of the runtime:

```
// Runtime #1                       // Runtime #2
1|15|26|31|41|54|61|76|83|97        7|13|28|35|43|58|69|75|83|91
5|13|28|33|42|50|64|72|89|96        4|12|21|32|41|52|64|71|89|93
8|16|23|35|44|58|67|79|84|98        9|19|23|34|40|54|60|76|80|95
4|14|22|34|45|55|62|77|81|95        0|18|29|33|47|59|67|73|84|90
6|18|25|38|46|53|65|70|86|93        6|11|27|37|46|55|65|72|82|99
3|10|27|30|48|51|66|75|88|90        5|16|20|30|44|56|63|74|86|97
2|11|24|39|40|52|63|74|80|91        3|10|24|38|45|57|61|78|87|92
7|19|21|36|43|56|60|78|87|99        2|14|26|31|48|51|68|70|88|94
0|12|29|32|49|59|68|73|82|92        1|15|22|39|49|50|62|79|85|96
9|17|20|37|47|57|69|71|85|94        8|17|25|36|42|53|66|77|81|98

// Runtime #3                       // Runtime #4
5|18|24|38|40|56|65|75|89|96        2|11|24|36|43|59|65|71|89|99
3|13|20|33|43|58|68|72|87|93        6|14|26|38|48|52|69|78|83|92
9|11|25|35|47|55|61|78|84|98        3|10|23|39|47|50|64|75|87|98
6|10|22|31|49|54|66|71|86|94        5|18|25|35|42|58|61|79|85|93
8|16|23|37|44|51|62|77|88|97        9|13|27|37|41|51|60|74|88|96
1|12|29|34|48|59|60|76|81|92        8|19|28|30|44|57|62|77|81|94
7|17|26|30|46|52|67|79|83|99        0|12|22|33|40|53|63|73|84|91
4|15|27|32|42|57|64|70|85|95        4|15|29|34|46|56|67|70|86|97
0|19|21|39|45|50|63|74|80|91        7|16|20|32|49|54|66|76|82|90
2|14|28|36|41|53|69|73|82|90        1|17|21|31|45|55|68|72|80|95
```

If you want to skip specific columns, add a conditional test:

```
if (x == 0 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7)
{
    row += ".|";
    continue;
}
```

Implementing this test, you can skip certain columns, producing:

```
.|14|28|.|40|.|64|.|85|99
.|12|25|.|41|.|62|.|80|95
.|11|27|.|44|.|61|.|87|91
.|16|23|.|43|.|69|.|81|94
.|17|26|.|45|.|60|.|86|92
.|13|20|.|42|.|65|.|89|90
.|15|24|.|49|.|67|.|88|96
.|18|29|.|47|.|63|.|84|97
.|10|22|.|48|.|66|.|83|93
.|19|21|.|46|.|68|.|82|98
```

Here's an example Flex implementation, producing a `DataGrid` of the result set:

> [image: random-matrix]

MXML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayList;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            [Bindable]
            public var data:Array = [];

            [Bindable]
            public var dataProvider:ArrayList = new ArrayList();

            protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                generateData();
            }

            protected function clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                generateData();
            }

            protected function generateData():void
            {
                dataProvider = new ArrayList();

                var x:uint; // columns
                var y:uint; // rows
                var n:uint; // number

                for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                {
                    data.push([]);

                    for (n = 0; n < 10; n++)
                    {
                        data[x].push((10 * x) + n);
                    }
                }

                for (y = 0; y < 10; y++)
                {
                    var row:Object = {};

                    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                    {
                        n = getRandomNumber(data[x]);
                        row[x] = n;
                    }

                    dataProvider.addItem(row);
                }
            }

            public function getRandomNumber(set:Array):uint
            {
                return (set.splice(int(Math.random() *
                                       set.length), 1)[0]);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <s:Button label="Generate Data"
              click="clickHandler(event)" />

    <s:DataGrid dataProvider="{dataProvider}" />

</s:Application>
```